# I cant create a paypal test app in developers account for Rest Api

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to create an paypal app for Rest Api.
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

I have created sandbox test US business account, but the account is not displayed in the 'Sandbox developer account' dropdown. Can anybody tell me wheres the problem?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsnYH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine now. 
Delete an existing test account if you have any and follow the same workflow again!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but Paypal won't let me delete the test accounts. The checkboxes to choose the accounts to delete are disabled.

Comment: I just went into the DOM and took the `disabled` property off the checkboxes and was able to delete them. Every time I create a sandbox user, though, if I try to open the profile, I see a message "We experienced some issues on our end while creating this Sandbox account. Please delete it and try again." And I still don't see my sandbox accounts in the drop-down when I go to create a REST API app.

Comment: @steve.hanson PayPal developer portal wont let you delete default test buyer and merchant account created. But however you can create new test (buyer and merchant) accounts and associate apps with them. that should help and also reaching out support team will help you resolve default accounts as well.  to create new account please go here https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/create

Comment: the issue was that Paypal wouldn't let me associate apps with the new accounts. I finally got it to work by creating a business account with settings: $100 balance, not verified by bank. Not sure if those settings were the magic that fixed the issue with creating an account or if the Paypal bug was fixed.

Comment: Actually couple days back we had an issue and all the accounts created that period had the same issue. However we rolled a patch and all new accounts should work fine.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and yes my account was also created at around that time. Can't create sandbox account successfully.